# play scala return two object

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

is there a wey to return both yields?

```
val process =
  for {
    processTemplate <- processTemplateDTO.getProcessTemplate(processTemplateId)
    processSteps <- processTemplateDTO.getProcessStepTemplates(processTemplateId)
  } yield (processTemplate, processSteps)


process.map(p => Ok(Json.toJson(p)))
```

I got this error:

```
No Json serializer found for type (Option[models.ProcessTemplatesModel], Seq[models.ProcessStepTemplatesModel]). Try to implement an implicit Writes or Format for this type.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to write a 2-tuple (x,y) to json. By default there is no  writes available for a tuple i.e play framework doesn't know how to convert it into json.

You can fix this by providing a writes, something like

```
implicit val writes =  new Writes[(A, B)] {
     override def writes(o: (A, B)): JsValue =
      Json.obj("field1"-> Json.toJson(o._1), "filed2" -> Json.toJson(o._2))
}
```

Also you need to provide writes implementation for `ProcessTemplatesModel` and `ProcessStepTemplatesModel`. You can read more about json support in Play framework over [here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaJson).

Comment: where do I have to define the writes?

Comment: and why do I need to set up a writes for each model? and how should It look like?